# how to build mlpack on window

Tags: linux, windows, machine-learning, build, mlpack

I found this machine learning library in this link:
http://www.mlpack.org/doxygen.php?doc=build.html
It guides building on linux.

Do anyone show me how to build it on window please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a wiki page that may be helpful:

https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/wiki/WindowsBuild

Sometime back, a 64-bit mlpack 1.0.12 installer was built that can be found in the comments on this issue:

https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/365

Comment: Did you built it already? If so, could you please send them to me?

Comment: I had followed the instructions in your link but it did not work! :(

Comment: There is an installer in the second link I posted.  Try looking at that.  As the wiki page says, building mlpack on Windows is a complex, tedious affair and may or may not work depending on the exact version of Visual Studio you're using, the versions of supporting libraries, and so forth.  I can try to help you debug further, but I would suggest downloading the precompiled version from the second link.

Comment: I've uploaded prebuild binaries: https://github.com/stiv-yakovenko/mlpack-windows-build